# Object won't display

Tags: actionscript-3

I believe I'm missing something silly here - I'm new to Actionscript and don't know all the ins and outs yet. I have created the following code, which should draw an opaque, magenta line, consisting of 20 segments, going from 0,0 to w,h where w and h are the width and height of the screen, respectively:

```
import flash.display.Shape;

const aspX:int = stage.fullScreenWidth;
const aspY:int = stage.fullScreenHeight;
function locateX(inst:Number):Number{
    inst *= aspX;
    return inst;
}
function locateY(inst:Number):Number{
    inst *= aspY;
    return inst;
}

var wave_samples:int = 20;
var wave_drawType:Vector.<int> = new Vector.<int>(wave_samples);
var wave_points:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(2*wave_samples);

wave_drawType[0] = 1;
wave_points[0] = locateX(0);
wave_points[1] = locateY(0);

for (var sample:int = 1; sample < wave_samples; sample++){
    wave_drawType[sample] = 2;
    wave_points[2*sample] = locateX(sample / (wave_samples - 1));
    wave_points[2*sample + 1] = locateY(sample / (wave_samples - 1));
}
var MyWave:Shape = new Shape();
MyWave.graphics.lineStyle(3,0xFF00FF);
MyWave.graphics.drawPath(wave_drawType,wave_points);
addChild(MyWave);
```

When executed in the debugger, this code displays the line as expected. When compiled, though, all I get is the background... What am I overlooking?

Bonus points to anyone who can give a better way to fill 'wave_drawtype' with [1,2,2,2,2,...] than the method shown :)

**EDIT:** The movie, when ACTUALLY published, acts as expected - 'Control > Test Movie > Test' yields nothing, however. Anyone know why? I will consider an answer to this question an answer to the entire post.

Comment: For the record: I know that this can be done in a simpler manner. The code is part of a much more ambitious project, thus all the extraneous bits.

Comment: I ran this code perfectly fine regardless of the debugger. Is this the only thing that is going on? Are you manipulating the stage size in any way?

Comment: Also what do you mean specifically by "a better way to fill" the vector? Currently your implementation is the fastest way to fill it. There are other ways of populating the vector that are slower, but are interesting to play around with.

Comment: Thanks @BennettYeates, that is exactly what I meant. I wasn't sure if there was some sort of function to automatically populate the vector without a loop.

Comment: Perhaps this has something to do with my setup... are you aware of any settings, commands, or nuances of Flash that can interfere with drawing? Do I need to create another layer to draw in, or something of the like?

Comment: Not that I know of, but I would probably try just drawing a simple object and see if that appears. That would help deduce if this really is the code you posted or something else.

Comment: Odd - when ACTUALLY published, the movie acts as expected. Using 'Control > Test Movie > Test' shows nothing, though.

Comment: Do you mean such wave? http://i.imgur.com/hfvrnxw.png

Comment: And about your problem, I think you have problem with aspX, aspY variables. Get stage size by this.stage.stageWidth, and this.stage.stageHeight ;)

Comment: Also, it's better to read stage properties AFTER the movieclip is actually placed on the stage. This can sometimes be unpredictable. You can add a listener to check for that: clip.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, handler);